# Infinity - Sizes vs Types

Tags: logic, infinity

Suppose there is a line, infinitely long in both directions. Make arbitrarily "uniform" cuts or "integers". Obviously there are infinitely many of these. And there are arbitrary "lengths" BETWEEN these units. Now, there are infinitely many WAYS("lengths") to chop each of these lengths into units. So we can see that there are different TYPES of infinities here - the AMOUNT of cuts vs WAYS of cutting BETWEEN those cuts.

So perhaps, it's not that there are different SIZES of infinity, but it's just that you are counting different things when you compare the "sizes" of, say, integers vs real numbers?

Comment: If you're just saying you object to the informal use of the word "size" when referring to the fact that the integers can't be paired up in a one-on-one correspondence with the real numbers: OK, What is your question?  -- And if you're saying you think people are incorrect about matching things up and it's just that the types of objects are misleading them, you're wrong but could post a question about the step in the argument you have concerns about to get that cleared up. --   If you're saying a third thing, it's unclear to me. Can you try rewording your concern?

Comment: What's with the CAPITALS?

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks. It seems that you at least see an analog to what I'm saying. So then a follow up question would be, does comparing cardinalities of countable and uncountable sets make as much sense as comparing sizes of a line and a rectangle?

Comment: @AlexZiro When comparing sizes of a line and a rectangle, what you're probably really thinking about is something like the Hausdorff dimension of the shape, that you need some measure theory to formalise. That, or, maybe, the dimension topologically or something. When we're strictly just talking about sets, there's really no difference between a line and a rectangle; it's just an uncountable set, and sets with the same cardinality are isomorphic. The intervals $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have the same cardinality (and are hence basically "the same" as sets), but have different measure.

Comment: @JackCrawford Thanks. What are some mathematical models that use uncountable sets instead of using the notion as a sort of a outer bounds of study?

Comment: I would be surprised if you found a single source that wasn't an introduction to the concept of countability that "used the notion [of uncountability] as a sort of outer bound of study" in the sense that subsets of the reals are important and there are more of them (in the sense of cardinality) than reals.

Answer (score 2):

No. The "number" of integers has nothing to do with how they are laid out on a number line. On a line, the point labelled $0$ and the point labelled $1$ forces all of the other integers to correspond to well-defined, unique positions on that line. There is a very clear one-to-one  correspondence between the "integers" of any two such lines and **ways** and **types** are just bothersome noise.